# duplicate answers in table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hi everyone i am working on a small beginner project currently i am working on displaying two separate table data on a web page in HTML table but i am having some problems with the data. There is a credentials table and an answers table a user first enters its credentials and then presses the button take survay which stores the credentials on to a table and redirects the user to a question page where he picks a multiple choice question and the users choices are saved to a table. all this data then is displayed on web page but when the data is displayed the answers get duplicated fore every user that enter its details. can someone tell me where have i gone wrong ? tnx for your help in advance.

**view**

```
 <table border="1">


  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Second Name</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Answer</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
 </tr>
  <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?> 
 <tr>

     <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->second_name; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $row->answerA;?>
      <?php echo $row->answerB;?>
      <?php echo $row->answerC;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->comment;?><br></td>

 </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

 </table>
```

**controller**

```
function getall(){

    $this->load->model('result_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
    $this->load->view('result_view', $data);

    }
```

**model**

```
function result_getall(){
  return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                 ->from('tblanswers, credentials')
                 ->get()
                 ->result_object();

}
```

Comment: You probably need to group the result by the credentials table. But I'm little unsure about how you structured your query. Shouldn't there be a join or so?

Comment: my tables daunt have any relational data between them i am only displaying them as two separate tables

Comment: can u explain more about how to group the results ?

Comment: If there is no relationship between the tables, then how do you expect it to know what credentials should be attached to which answer? You need to create a column that relates them (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting everything from tblanswers, credentials without joining on any column. You're ending up with a cross join, which pairs each row with every row from the other table. You need to specify which rows from tblanswers relate to which rows from credentials. E.g. if there is an id column in credentials then you need to create a credentials_id column in tblanswers and enter the data so that they match. Your getall() should look something like this:

```
function result_getall(){
  return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                 ->from('tblanswers')
                 ->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.credentials_id = credentials.id')
                 ->get()
                 ->result_object();

}
```

The line which says

```
join('credentials', 'tblanswers.credentials_id = credentials.id')
```

specifies how the two tables relate.

Suppose Mr Jones enters his credentials and they are saved in a row in the credentials table with id 72. Then he enters his answers. You need to make sure that when you save them, you enter "72" in the credentials_id column of the answers table. That signifies that these answers belong to Mr Jones. When you run the query with the join specified above, it will return Mr Jones' credentials against Mr Jones' answers.

Comment: tnx for answering .Can u tell me or give me an example how do i specify which row from tblanswers relate to credentials ?

Comment: would adding a foreign key to my tables fix this problem ?

Comment: Adding a foreign key would not fix it automatically. You would still need to add the join criteria. The main thing is to add the column that references a column in the other table. It is also good practice to specify it as a foreign key when you create it. If one person submits many answers, then the column in answers will be the foreign key referencing the column in credentials.

Comment: i understand that simply adding the foreign key will not fix my problem tnx for your help.